# Make all *debug* tags consistent

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

### Edited

There are a number of inconsistencies in how `*debug*` tags are named. This request is to make the naming of those tags more coherent.

My apologies to those who spent their time on the original version of this question. It was wrong of me to include an answer in the question. My only excuse is too many 20+ hour days working to meet a killer software development deadline. My suggested solution has been moved to an answer.

Comment: Why do we need so many "debugging" tags? Using two tags instead would be simpler and require fewer additional tags.

Comment: Why should questions about Visual Studio Code debugger be retagged to [tag:visual-studio-debugging]? VSC is a very different product from Visual Studio.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine the line says "except". This post has a lot of unclear bits, with that definitely being one of them, but they said that's a synonym that _shouldn't_ be made

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I would've never guessed it from the wording, honestly :)

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. It could have been worded in a way that was more clear.

Comment: @cb4 so... is Zoe correct that you *did* mean VSC *should not* be made a synonym?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine You pointed out that VSC is a different tool so obviously it should not be a synonym. For a site this mature, I expected there were best practices for solving the problem of inconsistent tag names within a topic. The solution I recommended purposefully allowed for flexibility because *I don't know what those practices are*. Maybe my assumption that they exist is false? Opinions from Tom and Ryan M are diametrically opposed. In either case, I did my part and raised the issue. Others can take it from here.

Comment: In a sense, the tag names *are* mostly consistent: they're the name of the specific tool or feature.  There are probably some things you've identified that *are* in need of cleanup (it looks like [tag:debug-diagnostic-tool] and [tag:debugdiag] should probably be synonyms, for one), but as a whole, the convention is that tags refer to specific tools or features, rather than what the user is trying to do at the time (e.g., debugging).

Comment: @cb4, I am just trying to gauge what `-->` means in terms of exceptions. *You* are saying those *should not* be synonymized, correct?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine The answer I wrongly embedded in the question has been moved to it's own answer and clarified: exceptions eliminated and `-->` defined.

Answer (score 20):

Many of these tags are about specific tools or features.  Making them more generic does the site a disservice.

[chrome-remote-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrome-remote-debugging) is a specific tool with which users may have problems and/or specific expertise.  [qdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qdebug) is a specific class which users may have problems and/or specific expertise.

We should generally *avoid* [*XYZ*-debugging] tags, because they would quite likely end up with questions about debugging *XYZ* programs, which really should just have the [*XYZ*] tag.

Comment: The community has spoken !-)  I see your point now about more vs less specific tags and agree.

Answer (score 0):

A non-exhaustive scan of questions using these tags show that they primarily are about a tool and a language (or framework, e.g. ".net"). While one tool may support several languages and one language may be supported by several tools, the most straightforward solution would use `<tool name>-debugging` as the primary tag name. For retagging questions that do not reference a debugging tool (e.g. [debug-backtrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debug-backtrace), [outputdebugstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outputdebugstring)), the most consistent option is tagging them with `<language>` and [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging). A less coherent alternative is tagging them with `<language>-debugging`. Not all languages have such a tag and introducing one for each language would IMO increase complexity without adding value.

I recommend keeping the `*-debugging` tags and making the other tags consistent with the "-debugging" suffix. This is one of several possible solutions and it may be suboptimal. I leave that decision to the Moderators. The `-->` operator means "gets renamed to". Steps to implement:

- (`*-debug` --> `*-debugging` ) and (`*-debugger` --> `*-debugging`)

  - i.e. rename all tags with suffix "-debug" and "-debugger" to "-debugging".
- `debug*` --> `<tool>-debugging` and `<language>`

  - ([debugdiag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugdiag) and [debug-diagnostic-tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debug-diagnostic-tool))

    - if tagged `visual-studio*` --> [visual-studio-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-debugging)
    - else --> [debugdiag-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugdiag-debugging)
  - [debugview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugview) --> [debugview-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugview-debugging)
  - [debug-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debug-build) --> most of these 31 questions go to [visual-studio-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-debugging) or [android-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-debugging); I have cleaned up a few
- [debuggervisualizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debuggervisualizer) --> `<tool>-debugging` and (`<language>` or `<framework>` or `<os>`) in that order
- `xdebug*` --> [xdebug-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xdebug-debugging) and [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
- [qdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qdebug) --> [qt-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-debugging)
- [django-debug-toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-debug-toolbar) --> [django-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-debugging) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (and/or [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django))
- [phpdebugbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpdebugbar) --> [laravel-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-debugging); 30 questions total; many mistagged, I have cleaned up a few
- [chrome-remote-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrome-remote-debugging) --> [chrome-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrome-debugging) and [remote-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-debugging) on all 42 questions; then delete